# Angular CLI dist url is not working in browser

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have created an Angular project, dist folder is created successfully after run the command `ng build --prod`.  After run the `http-server ./dist`

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./dist
Available on:
  http://53.88.125.168:8082
  http://127.0.0.1:8082
```

but when I click one of the above http url. Browser returns like

```
This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


    <!-- Polyfills -->
    <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app><!-- content managed by Angular --></my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Looks like some proxy issue. Experts advise please?

Comment: inside dist folder there will be another folder with your project name

Comment: so starting up http-server, serving `./dist` wont help as you have set the base to `/`

Comment: there is no folder with project name. only there is supporting files and assets folder. Based is already set /

Comment: did you check the console to see if there are any errors shown

Comment: run : http-server ./dist/{project-name}

Comment: No console errors. Tried this http-server ./dist/{project-name} still not working

Comment: can you share :
a) where you are running this command : {location}, it should be at dist level only
b) your elements inside dist folder snapshot

Comment: Added snapshots

Comment: cd to the dist folder and then run http-server

Comment: @Pankaj: Not working. If append index.html like this "http://127.0.0.1:8082/index.html" it is working fine but routing is not working.

Comment: can you post your complete index.html, or you can try http-server --ext=html

Comment: @Pankaj: HTML posted.

Comment: Have you tried using ng serve with --prod=true ? it might be an issue with your http-server setup.

Comment: @Pankaj: I tried ng-serve --prod=true got the error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded"

Comment: are you using angular-cli ? if not, i would suggest get your project configured for cli and try it from there. Usually, such errors are hard to debug just by looking at the files, hence unless you provide a the entire source on github something.

Comment: I'm using Angular CLI only.

Comment: @pankaj: I got the solution. It is due to loadchildren() routing issue. Thanks for the valuable inputs.